# Group by category when elements belong to multiple categories

Tags: python, pandas, pandas-groupby

I have a collection of data that is indexed by a set of ZIP codes. I want to aggregate these data according to proximity to another set of geographic features, let's say, distance to a nearby lake.

It's simple enough to, say, loop through each lake in one dataframe and apply a haversine function to return all zip codes within 50 miles. Or vice versa; I can easily loop through all zip codes and return for each a list of lakes within 50 miles of said zip code.

But I want to do this a bit more efficiently. If each zip corresponded to only one lake, say the closest, the simple way to do this would be to create a new `"lake"` column and then apply `groupby("lake")` to receive the binned data for processing.

What I would like is a technique for automatically duplicating rows before a group by. Say I had the following data:

```
        lake
zip
10001   Huron
10002   Huron, Erie
10003   Erie, Superior
```

I would like to call `groupby` to return the following:

```
group 'Huron'
zip
10001
10002

group 'Erie'
zip
10002
10003

group 'Superior'
zip
10003
```

Basically, is there any nice way to do this, or are you essentially stuck with the dirty loop-through-indices method?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Option 1**
`str.split` with `expand=True`, followed by `stack` + `groupby`. This returns groups.

```
g = df.lake.str.split(',\s*', expand=True).stack()\
           .to_frame(name='lake').reset_index(level=1, drop=1).groupby('lake')

for i, k in g:
    print(k, '\n')

       lake
zip        
10002  Erie
10003  Erie 

        lake
zip         
10001  Huron
10002  Huron 

           lake
zip            
10003  Superior
```

---

**Option 2**
`str.get_dummies`, my preferred method. This does not return your result in groups, but the `get_dummies` implicitly creates OHEs which you can translate into groupings.

```
g = df.lake.str.get_dummies(sep=r', ')

for c in g.columns:
     print('{}: {}'.format(c, g[c][g[c] > 0].index.tolist()))

Erie: [10002, 10003]
Huron: [10001, 10002]
Superior: [10003]
```